# Include Layout Over Existing Layout and scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a recylerview in `books.xml` file where I am showing some regular book records as a list. What I am trying is to include `books.xml` file in `activity_main.xml` file to show the books record in home window. I need to show this records as a overlay window over main activity window as user can scroll them vertically to see the whole records. Looking like below image
[image]

And this is my current `activity_main.xml` file. How can I achieve same result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.trioangle.goferdriver.MainActivity"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorblock"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">
    <ImageView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/homelist"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/list"
        android:tint="@color/white"/>
    <View
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homelist"
        android:background="@color/button_material_light"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <com.trioangle.goferdriver.custompalette.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_driverstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/offline"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:font="@string/font_UBERMedium"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homelist"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        style="@style/SwitchCompatStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch_driverstatus"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <com.trioangle.goferdriver.custompalette.FontTextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/ub__red"
        android:id="@+id/txt_checkdriverstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkstatus"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:font="@string/font_UBERMedium"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iv_line"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorblock"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"/>
```

Comment: What did you try and what doesn't work? It's hard to understand what's wrong here. Perhaps you looking something like this but I'm not sure. https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Comment: This is my current home layout xml. Need to Include the books.xml file to achieve the result like the image. is that possible? any suggestion

Comment: But why you just don't add recyclerview to your main activity? Anyway I added link to the android documentation about include tag.

Comment: when I am trying to add recyclerview to my main activity it is giving error 'E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout' problem but working perfect in my books.xml file. can not figure it out what's the problem.then thought if including layout can save me

Comment: Include will not help you:D It would be better to fix your actual error with recycler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout here is some tips